# Monte-Carlo method

Tags: statistics

I have a problem with my statistics task. It sounds like this:
"Using the Monte Carlo method, plot the dependence of a on b for a from -5 to 5, where $P (a < x-y < b) = 0.95$, where $x\sim N(0,1)$, and y is a uniformly distributed random variable from -2 to 2."  what should I do, where to start? until I have no ideas.

To be honest, I did not understand anything in the following answer:
"First find the probability distribution of random variable X−Y using montecarlo method.

1.Pick an x and y randomly according to their densities and then compute x−y. Do this N times.

2.Make a list x−y values.

3.Sort the list in ascending order.

4.Fix an b which is in [−5,5].

5.From count number of values less than b, call this k.

$\cdot$ If k/N>0.95:
Count from smallest value till you get the k/N less more or less equal to 0.95.
The value you find is the a

$\cdot$ If k/N<0.95:

No such a exists."

I tried to code it and I have a lot of questions.

First of all, I created a list for $x-y$.

```
 dif<-x-y
```

Then, I created a list of values of a, which is from -5 to 5

```
a<-seq(-5, 5, 0.05)
```

But now I must go to the 5-th item. It sounds like this: From count number of values more than a, call this k. What should I do here? I must take values from $x-y$, which are more than a? Then I should count $k/N$ and if it is more than 0.95 what is next? 
"Count from smallest value", but what smallest value?

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

First find the probability distribution of random variable $X-Y$ using montecarlo method.

1. Pick an $x$ and $y$ randomly according  to their densities and then compute $x-y$. Do this $N$ times.
2. Make a list $x-y$ values.
3. Sort the list in ascending order.
4. Fix an b which is in $[-5,5]$.
5. From count number of values less than $b$, call this $k$.
6. - If $k/N>0.95$

     - Count from smallest value till you get the $k/N$ less more or less equal to 0.95.
     - The value you find is the $a$
   - If k/N<0.95

     - No such a exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help
!

Comment: Were you able to get results?

Comment: Not yet, but the idea is clear . but I have a question: why we must fix b from [-5,5]? in the initial statement of the problem a is from -5 to 5

Comment: So you might be wanting to find $b$ as a function of $a$, can you figure what change it would require in the algorithm?

Comment: I must fix a from -5 to 5 and then from count number of values more than a?

Comment: You got it, I will add that in an edit

Comment: So I began to code this and the problem appeared. Let a is a list of values from -5 to 5. Now I must do 5-th item that is:From count number of values more than a call this k... And the question is: What is the greatest value of k I should choose in the loop?

Comment: Just count numbers of $x-y$ values between the $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I understood, thank you

Comment: In 6-th item you have:"less more or less equal ", I can't understand what you said